# In Ruby, how to trap a signal multiple times?

Tags: ruby, signals

I have a program that will trap <kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd>, but it can be trapped just once. When you type `exit` to exit from the irb session, the signal generated by <kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd> can't be trapped again. Any ideas? This is the program:

```
require 'irb'
#trap "INT" do
#    IRB.start
#end

Signal.trap("INT")  { IRB.start }

count = 0

loop do
    count += 1
    puts count
    puts "Value = #{@value}" if defined? @value
    sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that IRB sets its own handler for sigint when you invoke it, which overrides your handler. To fix this, you can reset your handler again, after IRB is finished, like this:

```
def set_trap
  Signal.trap("INT")  do
    IRB.start
    set_trap
  end
end

set_trap
```

This will cause a bunch of warning when you invoke IRB the second time though, but that's a general problem with invoking IRB multiple times.